# Lighhouse server invalid token - LHCI invalid token

Tags: continuous-integration, frontend, lighthouse, lighthouse-ci

I have installed LHCI(Light House CI) server on an AWS EC2 instance(or my own home-server). The server is up and running. I have the `url`

> I can add projects to the CI server with `@lhci/cli@0.3 wizard` and the project I create through client wizard appears successfully on the LHCI server.

**As successful result of wizard it gives me two token. Admin and upload token whih I use it in my client config(upload token)**

However, when it runs the auto-run and generates the report, the next step which is pushing data to my LHCI instance, it says token is invalid. I installed it on my own Linux box in my home network.

1. I thought it could be something wrong with my network and something dodgy happening. Then I installed it on EC2 and still same issue.
2. One thing I didn't find in the documentation is about whether the server needs to be HTTPS? (if you know this it could be a great help as well)

How come the upload token generated by the wizard is not valid ? what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. First, make sure the lhci client and server version match. It is thought that additional authentication factors have been added as the master version of lhci has recently been upgraded. In my case, the following error occurred and I solved it by setting the version to the same version.

Error: Unexpected status code 403
  {"message":"Invalid token"}